# SQL Server query to calculate total for number of weeks in a given month name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I need to create a report where I will just pass month (February) and year (2011) and want the `sum(total)` but output desired like this... I don't know how to calculate total weekwise

```
Week-1......Week-2......Week-3......Week-4....Total 
---------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example

Sample table, contains just 2 columns `thedate datetime, amount numeric`

```
select cast(datediff(d, number%1000, getdate()) as datetime) as thedate, number as amount
into testtable
from master..spt_values
```

The query taking month and year as params

```
declare @month int, @year int
select @month = 2, @year = 2011

select *
from
(
select
    amount,
    'Week-' + right(dense_rank() over (order by datepart(wk, thedate)),1) week_in_month
from testtable
where thedate >= cast(@year*10000+@month*100+1 as char(8))
  and thedate <  dateadd(m,1,cast(@year*10000+@month*100+1 as char(8)))
) P
pivot (sum(amount) for week_in_month in ([Week-1],[Week-2],[Week-3],[Week-4],[Week-5])) V
```

Note:

- `cast(@year*10000+@month*100+1 as char(8))` : first day of month
- `dateadd(m,1,..)` : first day month after

Comment: Richard thank you for the query...I am only getting data for Week-1 although I have data datewise in table from February 3rd to 16th feb.

Comment: @user edit the question with the query you are using, and some sample rows that don't get counted. You could try the sample table I provided and check at least that it works with that - then go from there to your query.